# upgrading drive of 2015 macbook air, such thing as too fast?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssd

I was considering upgrading the drive of a macbook air that i got and was amazed at the difference between some of the NVMe PCIe M.2 drives at around 3,938 MB per second and other SATA drives (which I am not wholly sure can be used anyway, even with adapters?) that are more in the 700-800s MB p/s.

Would the 2015 macbook air be a bottle neck thus making such a
    blazing fast NVMe M.2 drive a bit moot?

Comment: Rule of bottlenecks—it depends on what you're doing! If you're encoding videos all day, a faster hard drive isn't going to help. By contrast, if you're copying files all day, yeah that hard drive will make a difference.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, copying files reminds me, wouldnt it help things like a swap space when/if i max out the memory?

Comment: @RajP Fast storage pays you back in so many ways. Saved application state, temporary files to get written while you’re doing updates, NVMe storage is a game changer over the old access protocols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - storage is the one bottleneck here.

- the CPU is always magnitude of times faster than storage and the bus speed between CPu and storage is also faster than both specs.

Go for the speed if you are sure the drivers and connectors are compatible.